# Convert NSDictionary array values into NSString format for MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: xcode, nsstring, formatting, nsdictionary, picker

I have a UIPickerViewDelegate that allows the user to select a term from the picker and see the term's definition by using NSDictionary to access data stored in a plist file. I also have a MFMailComposeViewController to allow the user to email the term and it's definition elsewhere.

But I can't seem to get the term and definition formatted properly for entry into the email. I looked at various "convert NSDictionary to NSString" solutions, but none seem to offer what I need, including variations of `Term = [dict objectForKey:@"Term"]`.

Under viewDidLoad, I have the following:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Glossary" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.termArray = [dict objectForKey:@"Term"];
self.definitionArray = [dict objectForKey:@"Definition"];
```

My pickerView code includes this:

```
NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                          @"%@",
                          [definitionArray objectAtIndex:row]];
definitionLabel.text = resultString;
NSString *termString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                          @"%@",
                          [termArray objectAtIndex:row]];
```

The code for showEmail contains:

```
int definitionIndex = [self.termPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
NSString *emailTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Definition of %@", termLabel];
NSString *emailDefinition = [definitionArray objectAtIndex:definitionIndex];
NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The definition of <B>%@</B> is:<P> <B>%@</B>", termLabel, emailDefinition];

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
```

I would like the email title and message body to pull from the Term selected in the picker and the Definition associated with it. I'm sure it must be a simple formatting issue, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Okay. I got the Definition half to work (code updated above). But, as written, Term appears as "(null)". Again, I assume this is just a formatting issue?

Comment: Anyone?
The issue may be with the fact that the code that I was expecting would take the Picker selection and drop it into the Term field instead dropped the Definition. So I'm not sure how to retrieve the actual Picker selection now that the app thinks the results are actually the Definition linked to what was selected in the Picker.